# onClick function isn't fire when I click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, prestashop

I'm trying to execute a simple function which show a `alert(message)` and returns `false` when users make click in a specific button with this HTML markup

```
<input type="submit" class="online" id="comprar_boton" value="Agregar al carrito" name="Submit">
```

So I build this code:

```
$('#comprar_boton').live('click', function(){
    alert("Recuerda que para comprar necesitas escoger la cantidad!");
    return false;
});
```

I use live() because it's a Prestashop theme and it uses jQuery 1.4.4. Also I tested this one too:

```
$("#comprar_boton").click(function(){
    alert("Recuerda que para comprar necesitas escoger la cantidad!");
    return false;
});
```

But none works for me. I check my code once and once again looking for some mistake and can't find nothing. You can check it online at [this site](http://sandbox.tiendaleones.com/189-banderin-logo-home-club.html). What I'm looking for is when any users or visitor make click at "Agregar al carrito" button a alert popup saying something in that case says

> Recuerda que para comprar necesitas escoger la cantidad!

Now, this is really funny because I have another code similar to the one here at the same file but fired when I click in a button with ID = #comprar_boton_no and this one works. The HTML markup is almost the same:

```
<input type="submit" id="comprar_boton_no" value="Agregar al carrito" name="Submit">
```

And the jQuery code associated is this one:

```
$("#comprar_boton_no").click(function(){
    alert("Recuerda que para comprar necesitas escoger la talla y la cantidad!");
    return false;
});
```

This one can be tested at this [address](http://sandbox.tiendaleones.com/191-banderin-logo-coporativo-azul.html). So I'm totally lost here at this point. What is wrong with my code? Any help?

Comment: `I use live() because it's a Prestashop theme and it uses jQuery 1.4.4.` You realy have no idea..

Comment: @Bondye Tell me, 'no idea' of what?

Comment: @Bondye Yes, no idea of what?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the page is loaded before you assign a click handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#comprar_boton").click(function(){
        alert("Recuerda que para comprar necesitas escoger la cantidad!");
        return false;
    });
})
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#comprar_boton').live('click', function(){
        alert("Recuerda que para comprar necesitas escoger la cantidad!");
        return false;
    });
})
```

Comment: Yes, I check that before the call is inside `$(document).ready()` as I said before

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed the click event inside `$(document).ready` ?

If not, try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#comprar_boton').click(function (event) {
        alert("Recuerda que para comprar necesitas escoger la cantidad!");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: yes it's placed inside `$(document).ready()` function and your solution doesn't works

Answer (score -1):

If you want to enable click handler in any time on particular element use [JQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
    $(document).on("click", "#comprar_boton", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Recuerda que para comprar necesitas escoger la cantidad!");
    });
```

Comment: @denis-ermolin Nop, I try your suggestion and didn't works either

Comment: What page are you talking about? Sitting on 1.4 version is bad idea.